# Any one having access issues with claude-3-haiku or anthropic.claude-3-sonnet from boto client

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-bedrock

If any one facing access issues from boto3 connecting claude-3-haiku or anthropic.claude-3-sonnet. From UI it looks approved.But while executing code from boto3 it's throwing access denied error.

[image]

Comment: are you facing this issue from a AWS Lambda?

Comment: I am running local before going to lambda.

Comment: Make sure you are making api call within the right region.